# Fresh install of Ubuntu with i3wm

Tags: unity, window-manager, i3-wm

I would like to use the i3 Window Manager with Ubuntu and not Unity.

Since I am going to do a fresh install Id like to keep the bloat to a minimum.

Should I just install it normally with the Desktop version and  remove Unity and compiz or install the Server version and then install X and i3?

Is it the same or are there any things I should be wary of?

Comment: I have this same question... I'd love a super light ubuntu machine that doesn't have Unity at all. That from the get go only has i3wm.

Comment: Same - but I'm finding all my function keys (lenovo x1) are not working, can't figure out what util/binary is used for managing mouse (so I can check a dang box to turn off the trackpad, etc). Long road to get this working, but I do like i3 thus far. So perfect for how I work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To keep the system bloat to absolute minimum You can use `Ubuntu MinimalCD`. You can download it here:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD
```

After installing only a base system (it requires an internet connection), issue the following commands to install `i3` and `xinit` (it is required for `startx` to work) :

```
sudo apt install i3
```

And then

```
sudo apt install xinit
```

You can reboot now and after loggin in as user just run command:

```
startx
```

Enjoy Your minimal i3 ubuntu installation.

Comment: Too easy. :D I remember in the bad old days of SVGA adapters, analog monitor bandwidth and Redhat (pre-sell-out) having to edit X display configs and when Ctrl-Alt-Backspace killed X by default. (Insert picture of nonexistent graybeard.)

Comment: Very nice answer, this installation is fast and you get a fully working system that boots fast

Comment: I have made this the accepted answer. Really the most basic with `xinit` considered :)

Comment: Up to this day, Ubuntu's mini image can only work with BIOS and not UEFI, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). There seems to be a workaround for that, but you have do a little bit of tinkering.

Answer (score 21):

I also like to keep bloat to a minimum, and I personally prefer to start from a fresh Ubuntu Server install.

After installation, add the [i3 PPA](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html), and then execute:

```
sudo apt install i3
```

Wanting to have a fall-back environment, one could consider to install for example Xfce (just the core package), that would still keep bloat to a minimum:

```
sudo apt install xfce4
```

Note: This will not include a login manager. It may be seen as an advantage for people preferring to start from CLI

Comment: Note if you skip xfce you'll still need xinit for i3. http://leetschau.github.io/blog/2014/05/04/191733/

Answer (score 10):

I've been using i3wm for the past few days on Kubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Ubuntu derivative), and it's a bit different of an experience.

Since Ubuntu uses the LightDM Display Manager, you can install i3wm and give it a try alongside your current window manager.

Just install the proper packages using the following in your shell:

```
sudo apt-get install i3
```

Note that Ubuntu uses an older version of i3, due to the process that Ubuntu uses to upstream new packages to their repositories. You can also follow the instructions found [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html) from the i3wm site, to use the latest stable version.

Once you have i3 installed, just log out to your [display manager](http://static.davidedmundson.co.uk/lightdm2/person_select.png) which is what handles your login & starts your window manager. Click the window manager box & change it to i3, and login. You should now be in i3wm, and a prompt will come up to generate your configuration file & ask you which modifier key you want to use (Alt or Super).

Some basic keybinds to help you with your first usage:

```
Mod+Enter            # Starts a terminal session
Mod+d                # Brings up dmenu, which finds commands from your $PATH
Mod+Shift+e          # Prompt to exit i3wm
```

Your config file will be in `.i3/config`, and has a list of all keybindings. It's quite configurable, I have mine set so that `mod+b` brings up my web browser, and `mod+m` brings up steam. I also bound my windows switching directional keys to `hjkl` rather than `jkl;`to match vim keybindings that I use in every other program that I can use them in, and just rebound horizontal split to `mod+shift+v`.

You can also add things to your `.i3/config` that you want to run at startup, by using `exec` on it's own without a preceding `bindsym`. For example, I put this line in my `.i3/config` to change my background:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id feh --bg-scale ~/pictures/Backgrounds/background01.jpg
```

I also added in some others, like `exec --no-startup-id volumeicon` and `exec --no-startup-id nm-applet` for tray icons, for an ALSA volume icon & a network manager.

One thing that's a bit different is my updating process, I'm not running an update notifier so after I run updates via the command line, I run the following script to check whether or not the file `/var/run/reboot-required` exists:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
    echo 'A system restart is required.'
fi
```

A thing I like about i3wm is that I'm starting to use the command line a lot more, and learning a lot along the way. I recommend keeping Unity as a fallback, just in case you decide to go back.

The User's Guide on the i3wm website is very helpful, and should help you in getting started with further configuration to your `.i3/config`.

Comment: Im using i3wm with ArchLinux already. My question is what the most elegant way of installing it on Ubuntu is. But thanks for all the effort :)

Comment: Did you see the link in my post - for latest stable version?

https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html

This is what I used to install it, I found it the most elegant if by elegant you mean up-to-date & stable.

Comment: The question is how to deal with Ubuntus bloat. Namely Unity and Compiz.