# Installing i3WM on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, login, desktop-environments, customization, i3-wm

I am using Kubuntu 17.04. I tried installing i3wm by executing

```
$sudo apt-get install i3-wm
```

However, once I logged out, I saw there was no place to switch to i3wm like in Unity. Moreover, The mouse cursor had completely disappeared and I had to log in via the console and remove i3-wm for it to re appear. How do I install i3-wm correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer but You can try installing minimal ubuntu with only i3 : https://askubuntu.com/questions/595563/fresh-install-of-ubuntu-with-i3wm/898861

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/regolith-linux-desktop-supports-ubuntu-19-10), you can do the following to get `i3-wm` (without Regolith)

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:kgilmer/regolith-stable

$ apt install i3-gaps i3-gaps-wm
```