# Running i3 wm and not sure how to correctly remove the other gui and wm

Tags: gnome, i3-wm

I'm trying to create my own dotfiles.

I'm using the I3 wm as gui and don't need the wayland and gnome desktop environment.

Can i safely run the "sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop". and afterward still open the applications?

I'm starting the WM with a .xinitrc script.

Comment: One possible way instead of removing software is just start fresh with bare minimum install and then install what You need. Check my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/595563/fresh-install-of-ubuntu-with-i3wm/898861#898861