# Ubuntu Minimal with i3wm

Tags: i3-wm

I've installed ubuntu with the mini.iso option choosing no further packages

then installed i3 xorg xinit, got it all working but i3 doesn't open a terminal or when i chose the dmenu option it shows the list then closes on the first keypress (nothing appears to be typed)

Any idea what did i miss? i've been searching for an answer for a while no other guide or video shows anything different.

UPDATE:
Ok so the dmenu issue turned up to be a locale issue now fixed and working regarding the other issue it's really weird, only gnome-terminal which i didn't even install works as a terminal not zsh or bash nothing else installed loads on i3 for some reason but in cli works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595563/fresh-install-of-ubuntu-with-i3wm/898861#898861).

Comment: Thanks, i solved my issue since then but i appreciate your answer